Flutter custom shape scaffold in windows
i want to know if its possible to make a custom shape of the scaffold main window for windows?
I have searched everywhere and can't find any information about it.
I want to achieve a personalized container/scaffold like for example the one in the image, i will add later custom buttons like minimize, maximize and close (this is no problem).



(https://i.sstatic.net/5aZg4yHO.jpg)
already tried bitsdojo_window but just works to hide windows default bar and add custom butons like close, etc.
Also tried custom paint in flutter but anything let me customize the main window shape.
